# Extracting substring using an array of strings

Tags: javascript

I have a set strings in array that I use as filter

```
const LANGUAGES = [    "tamil",    "hindi",    "punjabi",    "malayalam",    "telugu",    "marati",    "sinhala"  ];
```

The target *string* will have unpredictable sequence of strings of comma delimited values within quotes (E.g. "text")

Possible examples are

```
const text = '["CineIndia","ENG SUBS","IR","SAVER","TAMIL"]'

const text1 = '["SAVER","NFT","CineIndia","ENG SUBS","Hindi","IR","SAVER"]'
```

I have attempted to loop through `LANGUAGES`  and use `indexOf`

How can I extract a value in `LANGUAGES` from something like `text` or `text1`

I have attempted to loop through `LANGUAGES`  and use `indexOf` .
But this is a bit prescriptive and I am looking for a smarter way to achieve the same

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` to return your string to array:

```js
const text1 = '["SAVER","NFT","CineIndia","ENG SUBS","Hindi","IR","SAVER"]'
console.log(JSON.parse(text1))
```

Now, you can use filter:

```js
const LANGUAGES = [    "tamil",    "hindi",    "punjabi",    "malayalam",    "telugu",    "marati",    "sinhala"  ];
const text1 = '["SAVER","NFT","CineIndia","ENG SUBS","Hindi","IR","SAVER"]';
const txtArr = JSON.parse(text1)
const filteredTxt1 = txtArr.filter(x => LANGUAGES.includes(x.toLowerCase()))
console.log(filteredTxt1)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that is to use `.indexOf()` in combination with `.toLowerCase()` or `.toUpperCase()` since what you are searching for is in a different case from the list of languages.

```js
const LANGUAGES = ["tamil",    
                   "hindi",    
                   "punjabi",    
                   "malayalam",    
                   "telugu",    
                   "marati",    
                   "sinhala"  ];

const text = '["CineIndia","ENG SUBS","IR","SAVER","TAMIL"]';

const text1 = '["SAVER","NFT","CineIndia","ENG SUBS","Hindi","IR","SAVER"]';

LANGUAGES.forEach(function(lang){
  if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf(lang)>-1) {
    console.log('the constant [text] contains ' + lang);
  }
  if (text1.toLowerCase().indexOf(lang)>-1) {
    console.log('the constant [text1] contains ' + lang);
  }
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you're trying to get the language of a text array from your defined language list right?

If so, here is your answer:

```js
const LANGUAGES = ["tamil", "hindi", "punjabi", 
    "malayalam", "telugu", "marati", "sinhala"];
const text = '["CineIndia","ENG SUBS","IR","SAVER","TAMIL"]'
const text1 = '["SAVER","NFT","CineIndia","ENG SUBS","Hindi","IR","SAVER"]'
function getLang(text) {
  const array = JSON.parse(text)
  let lang = -1
  const languages = LANGUAGES.map(x => x.toLowerCase())
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (languages.indexOf(array[i].toLowerCase()) != -1) {
      lang = languages.indexOf(array[i].toLowerCase())
   }
 }
 return LANGUAGES[lang]
}
console.log(getLang(text))
console.log(getLang(text1))
```